# how to remove user account from active directory in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

How to remove user account from active directory programmatically in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily googled, see

http://www.dotnet4all.com/dotnet-code/2004/11/how-to-delete-user-from-active.html

and here for the pitfalls using it with ASP.NET:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329986